# BeamerColor package

Tags: beamer

I had to reinstall MikTex and my presentation written in `beamer` doesn't work now. It's said that "`BeamerColor.sty` not found". i tried to download it again and install but it's still not working. I'd like to ask
1. How to download it from some webpage? When I did it I got `BeamerColor.sty.txt`. I tried to rewrite it as `BeamerColor.sty` but it wasn't helpful.
2. Where should I install the package in Mixtex?
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As far as I know, there is no `beamercolor.sty`. I edited your question a little bit, but it's quite difficult, since the underlying assumption is (probably) wrong

Comment: You can download the package there: http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~frank/latex-kurs/latex-kurs-3/farben/BeamerColor.sty

Comment: I know but how can I download it from there in .sty file and also where should I install it in Tex?

Comment: How to download it, probably depends on your browser. In Firefox, simply click right and something like `save page as` (sorry, I do not have an english version available).

Comment: After download, move it into the same folder as your tex file.

Comment: or if downloading does not work, open the link, select and copy all and paste it into a new document in your favourit latex editor and save it from there as `BeamerColor.sty`

Comment: An in what sense was "I tried to rewrite it as BeamerColor.sty" not helpful?

Comment: which editor are you using? Which operating system do you have?

Comment: Are there any news here?